# Como selecionar um formulário de contato específico para formatar no CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, plugin

Estou trabalhando num formulário de contato rápido na minha página, e preciso formatá-lo no css com o seguinte código:

```css
form.wpcf7-form {
position: absolute;
width: 250px;
top: 165%;
left: 65%;
text-align: center;
background-color: rgba(89, 89, 89, 0.5);
background-size: 300px 442.95px;
}
```

O código acima aplica a formatação para todos os formulários de contato no site, mas preciso que essa formatação se aplique apenas a esse formulário de contato.
Segue o short code dele.

```
[contact-form-7 id="4831" title="Contato Rápido"]
```

Como posso selecioná-lo no css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione uma classe diretamente no shortcode do seu form:

```
[contact-form-7 id="4831" title="Contato Rápido" html_class="form_rapido"]
```

E altere seu CSS:

```
form.form_rapido {
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    top: 165%;
    left: 65%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(89, 89, 89, 0.5);
    background-size: 300px 442.95px;
}
```

---

fonte: http://contactform7.com/faq/can-i-add-id-and-class-attributes-to-a-form-element/

Comment: Muito obrigado William! Usei sua dica e deu certo!

Answer (score 0):

coloque assim:

```
form#4831.wpcf7-form {
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    top: 165%;
    left: 65%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(89, 89, 89, 0.5);
    background-size: 300px 442.95px;
}
```

o # indica o ID do elemento html que vc quer aplicar o estilo

Comment: Seria outro jeito de selecionar esse id, não pensei nisso. Obrigado!

Comment: Caso alguma das respostas seja útil não esqueça de aceitar e/ou dar upvote,  grato